OR-Tools CP-SAT conditional constraint
In the problem I am trying to solve, I have a list of length n of boolean variables called x. Given an integer m where m < n, I need to define these two constraints:

if LinearExpr.Sum(x[m:]) > 0 then LinearExpr.Sum(x[:m]) == 0
if LinearExpr.Sum(x[:m]) > 0 then LinearExpr.Sum(x[m:]) == 0

From what I've read I should use one or several of the following:

AddOrBool
OnlyEnforceIf
AddImplication

However, after a few hours of trying I could not figure it out. Any help to solve this is very much appreciated!

  model.add_at_most_one(x)

This is the only working case if I am not mistaken.
Now, the medium answer for one of the constraint:
   model.add(sum(x[:m] == 0).only_enforce_if(x[m])

and finally the general one (still for one of the constraints):
   is_positive_before_m = model.new_bool_var('')

   # is_positive_before_m <=> sum(x[:m]) >= 0
   model.add(sum(x[:m]) >= 0).only_enforce_if(is_positive_before_m)
   model.add(sum(x[:m]) == 0).only_enforce_if(~is_positive_before_m)

   # is_positive_before_m => sum(x[m:]) == 0
   model.add(sum(x[m:] == 0).only_enforce_if(is_positive_before_m)


Hello Laurent, thanks for your answer. I didn't understand the last restriction. First, I think there is a right bracket missing in "sum(x[m:]" and I don't get the idea behind it.  If is_positive_before_m == 0 (meaning sum(x[:m]) == 0) then sum(x[m:]) == 0? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

And regarding your note, that is something I find confusing about Python but slicing x[:m] does not include x[m] in the result, but slicing x[m:] does.

ok, so ignore my note.

Thanks! I posted an answer of my own inspired on your answer but expanding on the logic behind it, and also providing working code to help a future reader. I will choose your answer as the accepted one.

Thanks to Laurent's answer I was finally able to achieve what I wanted. Here are the details for the implementation of each constraint:

if sum(x[:m]) > 0 then sum(x[m:]) == 0:

first_condition_bool_var = self._model.NewBoolVar('first_condition_bool_var')

# first_condition_bool_var <-> sum(x[:m]) > 0
model.Add(sum(x[:m]) > 0).OnlyEnforceIf(first_condition_bool_var)
model.Add(sum(x[:m]) == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(first_condition_bool_var.Not())

# given that first_condition_bool_var <-> sum(x[:m]) > 0
# to implement the first constraint we have to do the following:
model.Add(sum(x[m:]) == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(first_condition_bool_var)


if sum(x[m:]) > 0 then sum(x[:m]) == 0:

second_condition_bool_var = self._model.NewBoolVar('second_condition_bool_var')
model.Add(sum(x[m:]) > 0).OnlyEnforceIf(second_condition_bool_var)
model.Add(sum(x[m:]) == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(second_condition_bool_var.Not())

# given that second_condition_bool_var <-> sum(x[m:]) > 0
# to implement the second constraint we have to do the following:
model.Add(sum(x[:m]) == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(second_condition_bool_var)

The basic idea behind what Laurent showed is that to define conditional constraints in the CPSolver model, where the conditions are expressions and not just boolean variables, one has to define boolean variables that are equivalent to the condition expression.
In this question in particular, we defined first_condition_bool_var and made it equivalent to sum(x[:m]) > 0, and thensecond_condition_bool_var which we made equivalent to sum(x[m:]) > 0.
Here is the answer to another question that helped me understand this.
